the python requests module , how to check if page using 'POST' method or 'GET' method
How to use the Python "requests" module to check if the page is using the "GET" method or the "POST" method.
I expect output to be True or False, or GET or Post.
Expected code:
import requests
url = f"www.get_example.com"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.check_get == True:
    print("get")


Send an OPTIONS request.

Anything designed for use in a browser will generally respond to either.  APIs usually have specific requirements, which you find in the documentation.

You used requests.get() to fetch the page, which is obviously a GET request, so it seems you have already answered the question.  I am confused what you're actually asking here.

If you want to read data from a page, most of the time is GET

Sort of true but does not answer the question.

I’ve never heard of this not being true.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

i found the answer:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

def check_request_type(url):
    global method
    try:
        get_response = requests.get(url)
        if get_response.status_code == 200:
            return "GET"
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        #print(f"GET request failed: {e}")
        pass
   
    try:
        post_response = requests.post(url)
        if post_response.status_code == 200:
            return "POST"
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        #print(f"POST request failed: {e}")
        pass
   
    return "GET/POST"

# Example usage
url = f'https://signup.com/login/'
result = check_request_type(url)
print(result)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
